# create p2p-network with "save-option" in python

Tags: python, p2p

I need an implementation of network with nodes (<100) in python. Nodes can send response on all nodes and on two neighbor-nodes. Nodes can save small data. Does anyone know of such library?

I use btpeer http://cs.berry.edu/~nhamid/p2p/framework-python.html, but there is no "save-data"-option.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [doozerd](https://github.com/ha/doozerd) an interesting concept. I am not sure about consistency guarantees it provides though.